# How to get Google Charts to sort and give me correct answer

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

Okay so I have some data and I need to get Google Charts to sort 3 types of answers from several lines of code. How do I do that with my current code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current');   // Don't need to specify chart libraries!
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper( {
          chartType: 'PieChart',
          dataSourceUrl:'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEMFnOrrGDEAZy5YMi3H-aSfyzwtHhAmBJuJYZjXsI/gviz/tq?range=A1:B57',
          query: 'SELECT A,B WHERE B > 100 ORDER BY B',
          options: {'title': 'AASHAN OCEAN TRANSPORTATION METHOD', legend: 'none'},
          containerId: 'vis_div'
        });
        wrapper.draw()
      }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="vis_div" style="width: 700px; height: 700px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the document I'm talking about deriving code from. [[Document]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEMFnOrrGDEAZy5YMi3H-aSfyzwtHhAmBJuJYZjXsI)

If anyone could help it would be most apprecriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure what you mean by *sort 3 types of answers*

but it looks like you want to group the data for a pie chart

you can aggregate the query result with a `GROUP BY` clause

```
query: 'SELECT A,COUNT(A) WHERE B > 100 GROUP BY A'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper( {
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEMFnOrrGDEAZy5YMi3H-aSfyzwtHhAmBJuJYZjXsI/gviz/tq?range=A1:B57',
    query: 'SELECT A,COUNT(A) WHERE B > 100 GROUP BY A',
    options: {title: 'AASHAN OCEAN TRANSPORTATION METHOD', legend: 'none'},
    containerId: 'vis_div'
  });
  wrapper.draw()
});
```

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="vis_div"></div>
```

Comment: You have just saved me a lot of time. Thank you soo much.